# LogicApps: MSGraph API Read Shared Mailbox Only

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-authentication, azure-app-registration

My goal is to use the msgraph api via logic apps to query a shared mailbox and return the result for a keyword in the subject line.

[image]

Above is what i currently have written.

I would like to know if this query is correct.

What is the least privileged role i can give to an auth app registration or managed identity to achieve this task. ideally i dont want to give this app reg / identity permission to read anything other than the mailbox specified.

verify query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/@{items('For_each_5')}/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'sharedmailbox@example.com.au' and toRecipients/any(r:r/emailAddress/address eq '@{items('For_each_5')}') and contains(subject, 'keyword')&$select=subject,from,toRecipients,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `toRecipients` is not supported when using `$filter`. I would prefer to use `$search`. The query will be more readable

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/@{items('For_each_5')}/messages?$search="from:sharedmailbox@example.com.au and to:@{items('For_each_5')} and subject:keyword"&$select=subject,from,toRecipients,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview
```

The managed identity needs `Mail.Read` application permission, but you can limit access to specific mailboxes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I can't find the instructions to limit access to a specific mailbox, where can I find this?

Comment: @HarriS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0#configure-applicationaccesspolicy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps&preserve-view=true